# Firebase search by category name

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, search

I use **EditText** to **search** firebase data, code is perfect but can't data search. This is my java code and xml code, please find out what is error in this code and what I can do for proper work. I use many alternative methods like filterSearch but not proper work for me...

**This is my JavaCode**

```
EditText searchText;

    //searching..........
    searchText = view.findViewById(R.id.searchText);
    searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!s.toString().isEmpty()){
                search(s.toString());
            }
            else {
                search("");
            }
        }
    });

//searching..........
private void search(String s) {
    Query query = dbCategories.getDatabase().getReference("categories").startAt(s).endAt(s + "\uf8ff");

    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()){
                YPCategoryList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String name = ds.getKey();
                    String desc = ds.child("desc").getValue(String.class);
                    String thumb = ds.child("thumbnail").getValue(String.class);

                    final YPCategory c = new YPCategory(name, desc, thumb);
                    YPCategoryList.add(c);
                }
                YPCategoriesAdapter adapter = new YPCategoriesAdapter(getContext().getApplicationContext(), YPCategoryList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

**This is my XML code**

```
 <EditText
android:id="@+id/searchText"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="Search Category By Name..."
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"/>
```

[image: Firebase project]

Comment: I tried to help with an answer below, but am not certain if that *is* indeed the problem. Please note that "it doesn't work" is really hard to help with. So if my answer doesn't yet solve the problem, add more information to your question about: 1) The exact value of `s` you use to test. Even better, can you reproduce the problem with hard-coded search values? 2) Which exact line of code doesn't do what you expect it to do? What does it do? What did you expect?

Comment: If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find an [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-data-cheaper-705f5efec444) that might help.

Comment: Hey Naveed. Any update here?

Comment: Thanks to help me my problem is solved 

Answer (score 0):

A query in Firebase Realtime Database always consists of two parts:

1. An `orderBy...()` call that indicates what you want to order/filter the database on.
2. An `equalTo()`, or `start...()`/`end...()` calls to indicate what values to filter from #1.

You're passing a `startAt`/`endAt` but don't specify what field to order on, so you'll get no results.

To fix this:

```
Query query = dbCategories.getDatabase().getReference("categories")
    .orderByKey()
    .startAt(s).endAt(s + "\uf8ff");
```